# How can I install PostgreSQL and PostGIS on Ubuntu 14.04 and enable remote access over the internet?

Tags: remote, postgresql

I would like to install PostgreSQL and PostGIS on my Ubuntu 14.04 virtual private server that is hosted in a remote datacenter.
How can I enable remote access on them?

Answer (score 2):

To install PostgreSQL on Ubuntu 14.04 server:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

Create a database and a user to access it

```
sudo -u postgres createuser -P USER_NAME_HERE
sudo -u postgres createdb -O USER_NAME_HERE DATABASE_NAME_HERE
```

Test connecting to PostgreSQL

```
psql -h localhost -U USER_NAME_HERE DATABASE_NAME_HERE
```

PostgreSQL will ask you for your password. Then you should see something like this:

```
psql (9.3.5)
SSL connection (cipher: DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits: 256)
Type "help" for help.

DATABASE_NAME_HERE=>
```

To exit type:

```
\q
```

Add PostGIS support to the database

```
sudo apt-get install -y postgis postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1
sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis; CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;" DATABASE_NAME_HERE
```

**Enabling remote access over the internet**

Add the following line to /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

On the file /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf in section "IPv4 local connections" replace the following line:

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32         md5
```

By:

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5
```

Then restart PostgreSQL server:

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

Next, open pgAdmin3 and create a new connection using these settings:

```
Name: (describe what this connection is for here)
Host: 
Port: 5432
Username: USERNAME_HERE
Password: PASSWORD_HERE
```

With the same settings, you will be able to connect using QGIS.

**Obs: If you have done something wrong and want to purge and reinstall all PostgreSQL files to create a brand new installation, here are the steps**:

To remove everything PostgreSQL from your system:

```
apt-get --purge remove postgresql\*
```

Just purging the postgres package isn't enough since it's just an empty meta-package.

Once all PostgreSQL packages have been removed, run:

```
rm -r /etc/postgresql/
rm -r /etc/postgresql-common/
rm -r /var/lib/postgresql/
userdel -r postgres
groupdel postgres
```

Sources:

http://www.saintsjd.com/2014/08/13/howto-install-postgis-on-ubuntu-trusty.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514128/postgresql-server-remote-connection

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/02/enable-remote-postgresql-connection/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748607/how-to-thoroughly-purge-and-reinstall-postgresql-on-ubuntu